# The name of the variables are repetitive and there must be some way to reduce the code

Tags: flutter, dart

can this be reduced?
I think there must be some way.
One way or another.

```
switch (i) {
      case 1:
        clicked1 = true;
        break;
      case 2:
        clicked2 = true;
        break;
      case 3:
        clicked3 = true;
        break;
      case 4:
        clicked4 = true;
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I know nothing of `dart`, but I'm guessing it has array types....

Comment: Why don't you make list of click insted of separate variables?

Comment: One of the possible options is to change the profession. For example, instead of programming, bake cakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider making a list:

```
List<bool> clicked = [false, false, false, false] // Fixed list of size 4
// use new List() if unknown size
```

And in your code:

```
void setTrue(int i){
// Since i is from 1-4, and array index is 0-3, i-1 is needed
clicked[i-1] = true;
}
```

You can also toggle instead of just setting true:

```
void toggle(int i){
clicked[i-1] = !clicked[i-1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just checking them one by one?

```
bool clicked1 = i == 1;
bool clicked2 = i == 2;
bool clicked3 = i == 3;
bool clicked4 = i == 4;
```

Comment: Is there a way like (clicked+i)?